# Solving bitwise AND equation

Tags: c, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, boolean-operations

How do I find the variable local_18 from:

```
((int)(char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30)
```

I thougth it could be associative like:

```
((int)(char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) & 0x1fffffffU == 0x30 & 0x1fffffffU)
```

But `0x1fffffffU & 0x1fffffffU` doesn't cancel out.

Here are the types of the variables (and the whole system I'm trying to solve):

```
int difficult_part(void)

{
  int iVar1;
  size_t sVar2;
  byte local_28;
  byte local_27;
  byte local_26;
  byte local_25;
  byte local_24;
  byte local_23;
  byte local_22;
  char local_21;
  byte local_18;
  byte local_17;
  byte local_16;
  byte local_15;
  byte local_14;
  byte local_13;
  byte local_12;
  char local_11;
  
  puts("guess the first eight characters.");
  fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
  sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
  if (sVar2 == 9) {
    if (((((local_18 == 0x65) && (local_17 == 0x37)) && (local_16 == 0x35)) && // That's pretty easy
        ((local_15 == 0x35 && (local_14 == 0x32)))) && // That's pretty easy
       ((local_13 == 99 && ((local_12 == 0x66 && (local_11 == '6')))))) { // That's pretty easy
      puts("Well done, you can try to guess the next eight characters but it won\'t be so easy.");
      fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
      sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
      if (sVar2 == 9) {
        if ((((((int)(char)local_18 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x34) && // Here is where I'm stuck
             (((int)(char)local_17 & 0x7fffffffU) == 99)) && // Here is where I'm stuck
            (((int)(char)local_16 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) && // Here is where I'm stuck
           (((((int)(char)local_15 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x32 && // Here is where I'm stuck
             (((int)(char)local_14 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) && // Here is where I'm stuck
            ((((int)(char)local_13 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x35 && // Here is where I'm stuck
             ((((int)(char)local_12 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x61 && (((int)local_11 & 0x7fffffffU) == 100) // Here is where I'm stuck
              ))))))) {
          puts("I see you\'ve got some skills in reversing, but can you guess the next eight ?");
          fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
          sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
          if (sVar2 == 9) {
            if ((((((int)(char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30) &&
                 (((int)(char)local_17 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x62)) &&
                (((int)(char)local_16 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x62)) &&
               (((((int)(char)local_15 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30 &&
                 (((int)(char)local_14 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x39)) &&
                ((((int)(char)local_13 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x35 &&
                 ((((int)(char)local_12 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x34 &&
                  (((int)local_11 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x66)))))))) {
              puts(
                  "I must say that I\'m impressed but it\'s not over. Will you be able to guess the next eight characters ?"
                  );
              fgets((char *)&local_28,0x10,stdin);
              sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_28);
              if (sVar2 == 9) {
                if ((((((local_28 ^ local_18) == 1) && ((local_27 ^ local_17) == 0x54)) &&
                     ((local_26 ^ local_16) == 0x55)) &&
                    (((local_25 ^ local_15) == 0x51 && ((local_24 ^ local_14) == 9)))) &&
                   (((local_23 ^ local_13) == 7 &&
                    (((local_22 ^ local_12) == 0x57 && (local_11 == local_21)))))) {
                  puts("You're done !");
                  most_difficult_part();
                  iVar1 = 0;
                }
                else {
                  iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess");
                }
              }
              else {
                iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
              }
            }
            else {
              iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
            }
          }
          else {
            iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
          }
        }
        else {
          iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
        }
      }
      else {
        iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
      }
    }
    else {
      iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
    }
  }
  else {
    iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
  }
  return iVar1;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can't see a problem to solve. You compare two variables and use a bit-mask for one of them.

Comment: Sorry @izlin, I'm going to update my answer. I'm trying to get what `local_18` is from the hexadecimal values of the equation

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's 0x30 (in little endian), since 0x30 is less than 0x1ffff... & operator also can be thought of as "bitwise multiplication" - the mask would zero out anything, that it doesn't include as as 1 in binary form (kinda like multiplying by 0). But bitwise operations don't work exactly like arithmetic, so I'm not sure if there is a bitwise "division")

Comment: Okay, I'm super interested in what you're writing @divanov42

Comment: To make any sense of this code we need to know the declared type of `local_18` and the size of `int` on the given system.

Comment: Sure, @Lundin. It's a byte. I'm going to add the full system I'm trying to solve with the comments to where I'm stuck.

Comment: @divanov42 the endianess does not matter

Comment: That's not very helpful. What's a "byte"? It's some home-made, non-standard type.

Comment: @tstanisl  that's true

Comment: It is not an "equation" it's is an expression.  Moreover it is probably nonsense. `(char)local_18` is 8 bits wide on most implementations, so masking the lower 27 bits serves no real purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example uses a bit-mask. You can use it to ignore some chosen bits. In your example you have:

```
local_18 & 0x1fffffffU
```

where `0x1fffffffU` is your bit-mask. If you write this number in binary representation you get `0b00011111111111111111111111111111U`, three `0`s followed by 29 `1`s.

This is equal to 'Ignore the first three binary values of `local_18` and compare the rest to `0x30`".

Your equation is true, if the last 27 binary digits of `local_18` are equal to `0x30`.

You may want to google bit-mask, there are many good tutorials and explanations out there.

Some examples

```
local_18 = 0x30 -> true
local_18 = 0x31 -> false
local_18 = 0x80000030 -> true
local_18 = 0x40000030 -> true
local_18 = 0x80001030 -> false
```

Test code:

```
int main()
{
    int local_18 = 0x30;
    if ((local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30)
        std::cout << "true";
    else
        std::cout << "false";
   
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

After I've seen your code there are some changes. You are using the type `byte` for `local_18`, so the mask is pretty useless. You have one byte, cast it to an int (that is done by adding 0s in front of your variable), so everything but the last byte are zeroes anyway.
That means in your case the equation can be simplified to

```
local_18 == 0x30
```

You can verify it easily with my example code. Just add the `(char)` cast inside the `if`, to trim the int to one byte:

```
int main()
{
    int local_18 = 0x30;
    if (((char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30)
        std::cout << "true";
    else
        std::cout << "false";
   
    return 0;
}
```

gives the following:

```
local_18 = 0x30 -> true
local_18 = 0x31 -> false
local_18 = 0x130 -> true, the cast trims the int to one byte, so the 1 will be ignored
local_18 = 0x80000030 -> true
local_18 = 0x40000030 -> true
local_18 = 0x80001030 -> true
```

Comment: It seems you miss the `(char)` cast.

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear! Would you mind if I ask you the same about XOR operations if I don't get it straight away?

Comment: @Zilog80 You are right, I added another paragraph with an example for the cast

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica : If you have a follow on question, post a new question.  I am sure if izlin chooses to he will answer; but by posting a new question it will get viewed by thousands of possible users who could answer rather then just one. SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.